# List is returning only the last value

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hi i have the following function:

```
    Public Shared Function GetAbrechnung() As List(Of WochenBPlan)


        Dim wbp = New WochenBPlan
        Dim allBookings As List(Of WochenBPlan) = New List(Of WochenBPlan)

        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT DISTINCT d.ABTEILUNG, d.BEMERKUNG, d.BESTUHLUNG, d.RAUMID, d.ID, d.PERSONENZAHL, d.ADRESSE + ', ' + d.RAUMBEZEICHNUNG AS RAUMBEZEICHNUNG, d.THEMA, p.VN + ' ' + p.NN AS NAME, CONVERT (char(5), d.VON, 108) + ' - ' + CONVERT (char(5), d.BIS, 108) AS ZEIT, p.TEL FROM VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG_DISPO AS d INNER JOIN PERSONAL AS p ON d.PERSONAL_ID = p.ID WHERE THEMA = 'EVENT'"
        Dim objRS As SqlDataReader

        objRS = SQLrunReaderWB(strSQL)
        If objRS.HasRows Then

            While objRS.Read()

                wbp.Raum = objRS("RAUMBEZEICHNUNG")
                wbp.Zeit = objRS("ZEIT")

                If Not IsDBNull(objRS("ABTEILUNG")) Then
                    wbp.Bereich = objRS("ABTEILUNG")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(objRS("THEMA")) Then
                    wbp.Thema = objRS("THEMA")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(objRS("NAME")) Then
                    wbp.Mieter = objRS("NAME")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(objRS("TEL")) Then
                    wbp.Mieter_Tel = objRS("TEL")
                End If

                wbp.Personen = objRS("PERSONENZAHL")
                wbp.Bestuhlung = objRS("BESTUHLUNG")

                If Not IsDBNull(objRS("BEMERKUNG")) Then
                    wbp.Bemerkung = objRS("BEMERKUNG")
                End If



                allBookings.Add(wbp)


            End While


        Else

        End If

        ConnWB.Close()
        Return allBookings

End Function
```

My Problem is that my List which i have generated is just returning the last value. What iam doing wrong? Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your scope object inside the loop. If you do not, you will get only the reference of the same object, changing it and therefore will be the last modification that will contain the list.

try something like this:

```
Public Shared Function GetAbrechnung() As List(Of WochenBPlan)

        Dim allBookings As List(Of WochenBPlan) = New List(Of WochenBPlan)

        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT DISTINCT d.ABTEILUNG, d.BEMERKUNG, d.BESTUHLUNG, d.RAUMID, d.ID, d.PERSONENZAHL, d.ADRESSE + ', ' + d.RAUMBEZEICHNUNG AS RAUMBEZEICHNUNG, d.THEMA, p.VN + ' ' + p.NN AS NAME, CONVERT (char(5), d.VON, 108) + ' - ' + CONVERT (char(5), d.BIS, 108) AS ZEIT, p.TEL FROM VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG_DISPO AS d INNER JOIN PERSONAL AS p ON d.PERSONAL_ID = p.ID WHERE THEMA = 'EVENT'"
        Dim objRS As SqlDataReader

        objRS = SQLrunReaderWB(strSQL)
        If objRS.HasRows Then

            While objRS.Read()

                'declare here a new instance to add on the list
                Dim wbp = New WochenBPlan

                wbp.Raum = objRS("RAUMBEZEICHNUNG")
                wbp.Zeit = objRS("ZEIT")

                If Not IsDBNull(objRS("ABTEILUNG")) Then
                    wbp.Bereich = objRS("ABTEILUNG")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(objRS("THEMA")) Then
                    wbp.Thema = objRS("THEMA")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(objRS("NAME")) Then
                    wbp.Mieter = objRS("NAME")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(objRS("TEL")) Then
                    wbp.Mieter_Tel = objRS("TEL")
                End If

                wbp.Personen = objRS("PERSONENZAHL")
                wbp.Bestuhlung = objRS("BESTUHLUNG")

                If Not IsDBNull(objRS("BEMERKUNG")) Then
                    wbp.Bemerkung = objRS("BEMERKUNG")
                End If


                ' add the reference to the new object on the list
                allBookings.Add(wbp)    

            End While    

        'Else ---> you do not need this ELSE scope, just remove it

        End If

        ConnWB.Close()

        Return allBookings

End Function
```

Comment: Thank your very much, it works! I will accept your answer, but i have to wait 10 min.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new instance of WochenBPlan on each loop iteration. Otherwise you're just changing replacing the previously set values. Add this to your loop.

```
wbp = New WochenBPlan()
```